# click and download file at the loaded page after click with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

In python, I'm trying to download the file at the page which is newly loaded using selenium.

before download it, as a step, I want to make click work in the newly loaded page.

Does anyone know how??

thank you..in advance

this is my code

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.naver.com')

driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elemEmail = driver.find_element_by_name("query")
elemEmail.send_keys("[word search] months of the year /English notebook")
btn = driver.find_element_by_id("search_btn")
btn.click()

time.sleep(20)

driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

1. after executing this, 
   and want to choose the first thing.
2. after click the first result, want to click that '첨부파일'(sorry.. it's korean, it means 'attached files')
3. after click the 'attached files' button, I encounter small pop-up. I want to click '내 PC 저장'(it means save it on my PC)

it's a bit complicated, but could you help me??

[here is a picture!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grdJ9.png)

Comment: Add some code what did you try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Switch to the pop-up window to perform any action on that window.

```
 Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles();      
  Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator();
    while(i1.hasNext())         
    {       
        String ChildWindow=i1.next();
       driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);
      //Code to handle the locators on childwindow
    }
```

Refer this [Handling Pop-up and Alert in Selenium](http://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html)

Comment: I think this is Java and I found a way with using find_element_by_css_selector(). I can actually access the newly updated page.  Thank you :)